# FCM not opening activity again when app opened by clicking notification

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT  | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT| PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(body).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.atlantic_applogo).setLargeIcon(icon).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

It is working flawless when app is opened from app icon but when app is opened from notification, on clicking new notification nothing happens if app is in foreground.

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".Activities.IncomingCallActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="false"
            android:persistableMode="persistAcrossReboots"
            android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"

            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.IncomingCallActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

Comment: In the future, please just edit your original question and add any missing code or logs. Providing this stuff in comments isn't good as it is hard to read.

Comment: Which `Activity` is started when you launch the app? Which one has `<intent-filter>` with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER?

Comment: Sorry I solved my problem

Comment: Please post an answer to your question, or delete the question (if it is no longer relevant). This will remove the question from the list of open questions and possibly help others with a similar problem. If you answer the question you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's solution:

```
i.setPackage(null);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_NO_ABORT );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```